# Animate dotted path, one dot after another

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm using the latest version of [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) to draw and animate a `path` within a SVG:

```
var s = Snap('#svg');
var getPath = s.path('M15 15L115 115');
var pathLength = getPath.getTotalLength();
getPath.attr({
  stroke: '#000',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  strokeDasharray: pathLength + ' ' + pathLength,
  strokeDashoffset: pathLength,
  strokeLinecap: 'round'
}).animate({
  strokeDashoffset: 0
}, 1500);
```

While this is working fine (as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hofmannsven/EEe69/)), I want to make it a dotted line, animated one dot after another.

I've built a quick prototype with circles (which you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hofmannsven/xae3v/)), to illustrate the look and feel, but technically I want it to base on a custom `path`.

Basically I'm looking for a way to animate a dotted (complex) path; so a path with attributes would be as fine as circles on a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since stroke-dasharray can be an array of values you can leave the stroke-dashoffset at 0 and update the stroke-dasharray until you get to the complete line.
something like this although this example is not really smooth and optimized.

```
var s = Snap('#svg');
var getPath = s.path('M15 15L115 115');
var pathLength = getPath.getTotalLength();

var perc = 0;
var dotLength = 5;
var gapLength = 4;

getPath.attr({
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    strokeDasharray: 0,
    strokeDashoffset: 0,
    strokeLinecap: 'round'
});

function updateLine(){
 perc +=1;
    if(perc>100){
        perc = 100;
    }
var visibleLength = pathLength*perc/100;
var drawnLength = 0;
    var cssValue = '';
    while(drawnLength < visibleLength){
     drawnLength += dotLength;
        if(drawnLength < visibleLength){
            cssValue += dotLength+ ' ';
            drawnLength += gapLength;
            if(drawnLength < visibleLength){
                cssValue += gapLength+ ' ';
            }
        }else{
            cssValue += (visibleLength + dotLength - drawnLength)+ ' ';
        }
    }
    cssValue += pathLength;
    if(perc<100){
     setTimeout(updateLine, 100);
    }
    getPath.attr({
        strokeDasharray: cssValue
    });
}

updateLine();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EEe69/7/

If you want the gaps to be "skipped" on the animation, you should substract them from the pathLength

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [d3](http://d3js.org/)?

There's an example doing something similar with a dotted line, based on mouse movement. I [started](http://jsfiddle.net/EEe69/5/) a timed function to do what you're looking to do, but I think you can figure it  out :)

Look at this part, and see if you can adjust it to do a specific path instead of d3.mouse:

```
d3.timer(function(step) {
    var svgagain = d3.select("body").select("svg")
        .on("mousemove", function() { var pt = d3.mouse(this); tick(pt); });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately `d3.min.js` is something about ~147KB, and it would be great not to load another JavaScript library, but I will keep it in mind!