# How to animate stroke-dasharray with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to animate `stroke-dasharray` with Snap.svg but didn't get it to work: nothing happens. The goal is to animate a straight line into a dashed line.

**SVG**

```
<svg>
    <line fill="none" stroke="#008D36" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="175" y1="153" x2="175" y2="21" id="Line"/>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
line {
    stroke-dasharray: 0,0;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    var s = Snap('svg');
    var l = s.select('#Line');
    l.animate({'stroke-dasharray':'1,20'}, 500);
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4pxW/5/

Comment: Maybe this question may help you: [Animate dotted path, one dot after another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24599229/1815847)

Comment: Hmm, in fact I want to animate a straight line into a dashed line. So I had to draw two lines: one straight line and one dashed line, while the straight line should become shortener and the dashed line longer. Too complicated/too much code/too much unnecessary SVG code for a simple effect. It seems that this sort of animation isn't possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what effect you are going for, but you should be able to animate it. There's a couple of different ways to animate, and maybe for this specific example I would try Snap.animate...

```
var s = Snap('svg');
var l = s.select('#Line');

Snap.animate(0,20, function( value ) {
    l.attr({ 'stroke-dasharray': '1,' + value});
}, 2000);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4pxW/6/)

Comment: @Ian found this answer from finding a reason why I can't translate Snap.animtate to element.animate for strokeDashoffset. Can you please specify more detailed why snap.animate in this specific case is the correct way and why element.animate isn't doing it's expected job? Thanks

Comment: I was assuming that maybe it doesn't know how to animate a dasharray string, so building the string it within the animation, would do the job. It also looks like strokeDasharray also gets set as css, whereas snap tends to animate svg attributes as well (which I personally think is possibly a bug).